# google analytics - api is not working?

Tags: google-analytics-api

i just start one internal server, to show info from our sites! 
and we intend to centralize all analytics data in one internal page,

so i try API from google...   (in this example page : https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/ )

it supose to return one graphic with accessed numbers by users

but get just one blank page... 
of couse I put my ClientID...

any help? any tips?
thanks in advance!!

[]s Sena

PS:
here is the code i have working on just, download from the link, note that i used my ClientID..
(49803909)

Comment: 49803909 is not a valid client id.  create a client id on google developer console

Comment: mmmmm   i did not expect that...
sorry,  maybe that is the problem

the id looks like this?:
1234567890ab-urc2eukdp2ddt4lmb3ropfv66bp0n587.apps.googleusercontent.com


so... how to have one real working example??

the tutors that i have never mentioned this!!!
thanks in advance

Comment: i just try again with this ID, but, again not working.

any tips?

Comment: I know I contacted the API team that they need to add something on that page about what a client id is  check these might help:  http://online-behavior.com/analytics/embed-api  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide